# MYSQL Stored procedure to fetch entire row from a table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-8.0, sql-procedure

I am a beginner to SQL and currently practicing the concept of the stored procedure. I have a table Fetch_Marks that contains 20 records with Student_No and Marks as columns. Now I would like to create a stored procedure for this in which the input parameter will be Student_No and when we enter the input (Let's say I gave the Student_No as 1), it should fetch the row of that particular student from the table Fetch_Marks. Is there any workaround for this? If yes, please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically don't need a procedure for that.

Procedures get interesting with CURSOR and LOOP when you need "normal" programming besides SQL to makes some thong much more complex

```
DROP procedure IF EXISTS `proc_get Student`;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `proc_get Student` ( IN _student_no BIGINT)
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM Fetch_Marks WHERE Student_No  = _student_no;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

But I am guessing this is some kind of homework, the variable _student_no is as it is because you have so a optical marker that it is a locally defined variable

Here's another example:
In this, we are adding a second IN variable and in which both are checked if they are NULL or NOT and then selects the wanted data

```
DROP procedure IF EXISTS `proc_get Student`;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `proc_get Student`( IN _student_no BIGINT,IN _roll_no BIGINT)
BEGIN
    IF ( _student_no IS NOT NULL AND _roll_no IS NULL) THEN
        SELECT * FROM Fetch_Marks WHERE Student_No  = _student_no;
    END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: yes you can but you have to check IS NULL

Comment: Thanks again, even this one worked but I'm curious why it is not fetching any data when I used <> (not equal to) null instead of not null

Comment: Mysql only allows NULL ckecks with IS NULL, as you notoved <> is not perogramed in. Please [accept the answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) if ot helps

Comment: Ooh yeah why not, I actually forgot about it. By the way, if you don't mind can you add a line explaining about the second procedure in your answer so that the one who's searching for this answer doesn't get confused.